# DolphinDB can't write to stream after renaming subtable

Tags: dolphindb

code as follow and executed

```
share streamTable(10000:0,`timestamp`temperature, [TIMESTAMP,DOUBLE]) as pubTable
share streamTable(10000:0,`ts`temp, [TIMESTAMP,DOUBLE]) as subTable1
share streamTable(10000:0,`ts`temp, [TIMESTAMP,DOUBLE]) as subTable2
topic1 = subscribeTable(, "pubTable", "actionName1", -1, subTable1, true)
topic1 = subscribeTable(, "pubTable", "actionName2", -1, myhandler, true)
vtimestamp = 1..10  
vtemp = 2.0 2.2 2.3 2.4 2.5 2.6 2.7 0.13 0.23 2.9
tableInsert(pubTable,vtimestamp,vtemp)
```

then executed the following code

```
share streamTable(10000:0,`ts`temp, [TIMESTAMP,DOUBLE]) as subTable1
share streamTable(10000:0,`ts`temp, [TIMESTAMP,DOUBLE]) as subTable2
tableInsert(pubTable,vtimestamp,vtemp)
```

found that no data was written

why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
share streamTable(10000:0,`ts`temp, [TIMESTAMP,DOUBLE]) as subTable1
share streamTable(10000:0,`ts`temp, [TIMESTAMP,DOUBLE]) as subTable2
```

The code above re-define these two tables: subTable1 and subTables. So these two subscribers cannot find the original tables.